# Ionic Android app can't display colors with transparency

Tags: android, ionic-framework, colors, android-webview

It seems like colors with transparancy are not working in my ionic android app.

while this works:

```
background-color: #cb003a;
```

this won't work:

```
background-color: #cb003aa4;
```

It will just be white.

But only in the android app, It works fine when serving it in the browser.

Can android show transparent colors?

Comment: "Can android show transparent colors?" - Yes, it can. Can't tell you more, cause I don't develop in ionic-framework.

Comment: @Maksym I don't know what I can explain further. I just set the background-color as explained on a HTML div and it will show up white... Thanks for the help though

Answer (score 3):

You should use RGBA.

```
background-color: rgba(203, 0, 58, 0.6431372549019608);
```